# After turn on my Locatiion Service, i would like to load my view

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xib

In my Application when i log in, after that Home screen will load at that time in my ViewDidLoad method of Home screen check that location service is ON or not . If it is not turn on then it will appear Error Screen.

Above functionality work fine but after that user immediately go to the setting of their cell , turn ON location service and again tap on  application that is running in background will load Home screen  and hide Error Screen.

```
if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]==YES)
{
    NSLog(@"Location Services Enabled");
    if([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]==kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied)
    {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"App Permission Denied"
                                           message:@"To re-enable, please go to Settings and turn on Location Service for this app."
                                          delegate:nil
                                 cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                 otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];

        [LocationGuideview setHidden:NO];

    }
}
```

so please tell me how its possible ?????????

Comment: Try shifting your code from viewdidLoad to viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear that should do it.

Comment: @NSDumb i already tried but its not working...

Comment: when you come from BG to FG can you apply a break point to all the methods so that we come to know which method gets called

Comment: ya i put break point their but not work ...

Answer (score 1):

What you can try here is add the above code in the application delegate.m file in the applicationDidEnterForeGround and maintain a flag in the plist or user default which you can access across your project

Your code would be something like this then

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application 
{
//check for location service
if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]==YES)
{
NSLog(@"Location Services Enabled");
// store a value in plist or user default for further reading set it to YES or whatever you like
}else{
 // Location services are not enabled set NO as flag value
}
}
```

Then inside your view controller in the view did load or view will appear you can read the stored value and do your stuff.

If you are using user defaults please use the synchronize method.

Comment: @MAC113 : did this answer solve your query ? please let me know OR did you find another solution please share the same.